# Iterate without output

Tags: pug

This may be a dumb question, but when I try to iterate using while, unless I output the var, it crashes. I simply what to use the while loop without outputting the count

This works, but not what I want:

```
  - var n = 0
              while n < 4 
                    li= n++
```

This is what I want:

```
  - var n = 0
              while n < 4 
                    li 
                    n++
```

Answer (score 0):

found it, I needed a hyphen for n

```
  li
     - n++
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11864672)

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin This is their solution to the problem. It should *not* be an edit.

Comment: @Rob that's fine; then, I's suggest ok1ha to include the full code snippet in the answer, and then proceed to accept his own answer